# Erroe Route [verification.verify] not defined Laravel Fortify

Tags: laravel

estoy trabajando con Laravel Forify para la autentificacion, pero tengo el siguiente error al crear un nuevo usuario: Route [verification.verify] not defined.

El registro se inserta pero aparece ese error...Leyendo en internet deje la ruta asi en mi archivo web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::view('home', 'home')->name('home');
});
```

pero aun asi el error persiste...

Saludos a todos

Comment: en ningun lado, solo instale el paquete siguiendo la documentacion, la ruta que coloque la tengo en el archivo de rutas web.php

Comment: Revisa si el modelo User no está implementando  MustVerifyEmail en la definición de la clase

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ estimado, efectivamente en el modelo estaba implementando MustVerifyEmail, lo elimine y ahora si funcina si el error e vista no encontrada...saludos codiales

Comment: Vale Nicolas. Si te animas escribe una respuesta con cómo lo resolviste y márcala como aceptada (aclarando que tú no querías implementar esa caraterística de verificación por email al registrase un nuevo usuario), de esa manera guiarás a otros usuarios que se encuentren con el mismo problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

todo dice que la ruta no esta definida que coloque true en ...
El error es porque esa ruta no esta definida, puedes comprobarlo corriendo el comando

```
php artisan route:list
```

@vicmans tiene algo de razon.

Lo que realmente pasa:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {

 (['auth:sanctum', 'verified']
```

Al pasar dos argumentos de laravel una de autenticacion y la otra de verificacion de correo. Dice: esta autenticado.  y verificado  ok response: Responde que el usuario en la tabla: User email_verified_at no esta registrado la fecha de activacion del correo, es decir que no me ha dicho que el correo existe. ps pasa una excecion para eso hay una pagina que debes activas como response a esto.. es decir como respuesta a esto...
Tu correo no esta verificado aun que la pagina esta creada ya sea en vue en blade o en limewire en la carpeta auth..

en App\Models\User busca

```
 // use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

activalo:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
```

eh implementalo

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
```

ahora faltan muchas cosas..
verificamos que kernel este activo los siguienes parámetros:

en la ruta App\Http\Kernel.php

```
// 'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
```

este:

```
'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
```

En la carpeta Config:
config\fortify.php
esto:

```
    // Features::emailVerification(),
```

este asi

```
    Features::emailVerification(),
```

Y los mas importante de este infierno de autenticación.. las rutas:
puedes hacer los diferentes tipos de rutas tu eliges.. pero una según tus recursos o proyecto.

basico:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->middleware('verified')->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum','verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

un poco de adrenalina:

```
Route::group(["middleware" => ['auth:sanctum','verified']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Dashboard');
        // return "hola william";
    })->name('dashboard');
    //aca puedes segir colocando las paginas o recursos que quieres cargar mientras en usuario este autenticado y verificado...
});
```

de donde sale el error
Route [verification.verify] not defined

de esta ruta/archivo..
vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailsVerified.php

function:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    if (! $request->user() ||
        ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
        ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
                ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                : Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice'));
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

linea:

```
: Redirect::guest(URL::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice'));
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque esa ruta no esta definida, puedes comprobarlo corriendo el comando

`php artisan route:list`

Con esto verificas si esta o no definida la ruta.

Esa ruta proviene del paquete `laravel/fortify`, por lo que no la veras en tu archivo `web.php`. Para ello debes ir al archivo `config/fortify.php` y en el arreglo `features` comprobar que esta habilitado `emailVerification()`

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
...

'features' => [
    ...
    Features::emailVerification(),
    ...
],
```

Acá puedes verlo en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#email-verification